# How come the condition of this for loop is still satisfied?

Tags: c++

I have a strange bug in my code:

```
vector<int> myVect;
for( int i =0; i< myVect.size() -1; i++)
{
    cout<< "how come I can reach this point?" << endl;
}
```

The ouput will be "how come I can reach this point?"

I still do not understand it. MyVect.size() is 0 as this vector is empty. Why is the condition in for loop still satisfied?

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Try `i + 1 < myVect.size()`...

Comment: Try printing `myVect.size() - 1`

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: modulo arithmetic strikes again!

Answer (score 6):

`myVect.size()` returns an unsigned integer.  Since the vector is empty it will be 0.  When you subtract 1 from that it wraps around and becomes the largest value that `std::vector::size_type`(generally `std::size_t`) can hold.

Since `i` which is 0 is less than that you satisfy the condition and enter the for loop.

Do note that starting in C++11 [ranged based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) were introduced.  If you want to loop through a container and use its values you can use

```
for (const auto & e : container_name)
    // use e here in a read only manner.
```

If you need to modify the elements then you can use

```
for (auto & e : container_name)
    // use e here however you want.
```

This guarantees that you loop through all of the elements of the container and is generally less error prone.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of veccot::size() is `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. If you subtract from 0 (unsigned), the number is 'wrapped around' back to the maximum possible value for a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered that the reason you subtract 1 from unsigned 0, solution to fix your issue is to change condition to:

```
for( int i =0; i + 1 < myVect.size(); i++)
```

Comment: Why not just start `i` at 1?

Comment: Because `i` may be used inside loop as array index and starting from 1 will require to verify/modify that code.

Comment: Ah yes.  There is that to consider.